# How to substract values by date from array

Tags: php, arrays, intervals

I have  the following array and i need to make the difference of values for each interval

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Mark] => 0
            [ID] => 6236
            [Date] => 2015-03-16 12:04:21
            [Value] => 2
           )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Mark] => 0
            [ID] => 6236
            [Date] => 2015-04-16 12:04:21
            [Value] => 4
           )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Mark] => 0
            [ID] => 6236
            [Date] => 2015-05-16 12:04:21
            [Value] => 9
           )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Mark] => 0
            [ID] => 6236
            [Date] => 2015-06-16 12:04:21
            [Value] => 15
           )
   )
```

and I need to make the difference for each interval.
something  like

```
[Date] => 2015-04-16 12:04:21 => [Value][1] - [Value][0] = 2
[Date] => 2015-05-16 12:04:21 => [Value][2] - [Value][1] = 5
[Date] => 2015-06-16 12:04:21 => [Value][3] - [Value][2] = 6
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You loop the array starting from 1 and subtract the value from the previous index

Comment: Show some attempt that you have made, otherwise it looks like you just want someone else to do your work for you.

Comment: Belive me, i've tried for 2 weeks in various ways. I've posted here as last resort. :( i'm a verry stubborn guy. :)  i  didn't know what to post first so i thought that someone will come up with  a brand new idea.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through this array to create new one with those differences, for example:

```
function get_differences($array){
    $new = array();
    foreach($array as $k=>$a){
        if(isset($array[$k-1])){
            $new[$a['Date']] = $a['Value']-$array[$k-1]['Value'];
        }
    }
    return $new;
}
```

To make sure your dates are in the same order as the keys, sort it by date first using `usort` function:

```
function sortdate($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($a['Date']) - strtotime($b['Date']);
}
usort($array, 'sortdate');

$new = get_differences($array);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2015-04-16 12:04:21] => 2
    [2015-05-16 12:04:21] => 5
    [2015-06-16 12:04:21] => 6
)
```

Comment: All of the above are more or less corect, but for safety i'll need to compare dates also

Comment: Thank you all for spending time to help me :)

Comment: @Goendg You're welcome! But you might mark one of the answers as accepted if any of them turned out to be useful for you.

Comment: as i rwote in title "How to substract values by date from array" i need to do that by DATE!  So, no, i did not get my answer

Comment: @Goendg I assumed that "by date" means that the keys are date, looks like I didn't understand (and still don't) what you really mean, I would like to make it as you wish - do you want to add the difference in days to this array?

Comment: i need to chech what's the smallest (let's call it X) date and after that what's the closest from all (Y) and then calculate the difference of valiues from Y-X. next step fint the closest to Y (Z) and calculate the difference of Z-Y, so on

Comment: @Goendg OK, I got it - you mean the dates are not always in the same order as keys of that array. I added sorting, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your array = $temp

you may do this

```
$temp_2 = array();
$result = array();

foreach($temp as $k => $arr){

    if(!count($temp_2)){

        $temp_2 = $arr;

        continue;

    }
    $t = array();
    $t[Date] = $arr[Date];
    $t[Value] = $arr[Value] - $temp_2[Value];
    $result[] = $t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Created new array and it will give you all intervals.
    <?php
    $arr = array(
        array(
            'Mark' => 0,
            'ID' => 6236,
            'Date' => '2015-03-16 12:04:21',
            'Value' => '2'
        ),
        array(
            'Mark' => 0,
            'ID' => 6236,
            'Date' => '2015-04-16 12:04:21',
            'Value' => '4'
        ),
        array(
            'Mark' => 0,
            'ID' => 6236,
            'Date' => '2015-05-16 12:04:21',
            'Value' => '9'
        ),
        array(
            'Mark' => 0,
            'ID' => 6236,
            'Date' => '2015-06-16 12:04:21',
            'Value' => '15'
        ),

    );

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);

    $newArr = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach($arr as $eachArr){
        foreach($eachArr as $k => $v){
            $newArr[$i][$k] = $v;
            if($i==0){
                $newArr[$i]['interval'] = 0;
            }else{
                $newArr[$i]['interval'] = $newArr[$i][$k] - $newArr[$i-1][$k];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo '<<br>';
    print_r($newArr);
```